# LINQ is provoking a System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nullreferenceexception

**The related post for System.NullReferenceException doesn't help, please avoid linking that or marking as duplicate!**

Code purpose: Check if the `docType` (a string variable) is present on a list of strings `replaceEntitiesConfig.DocTypes`.

Code that works:

```
private bool MustReplaceEntities(DocumentRequestModel docRequest, DocumentRequestOptions requestedInfo)
{
    var replaceEntitiesConfig = this.ConfigurationManager.GetModel<ReplaceEntitiesConfigModel>(ConfigurationModels.ContextualMenus, this.ApplicationContext.Application.ProductId);
    if (requestedInfo.Text && !replaceEntitiesConfig.DocTypes.IsEmpty())
    {
        var docType = this.GetDocument(docRequest, new DocumentRequestOptions { DocType = true }, DecoratorTypes.None).DocType;
        foreach (var configuredDocType in replaceEntitiesConfig.DocTypes)
        {
            if (configuredDocType.Equals(docType, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
private bool MustReplaceEntities(DocumentRequestModel docRequest, DocumentRequestOptions requestedInfo)
{
    var replaceEntitiesConfig = this.ConfigurationManager.GetModel<ReplaceEntitiesConfigModel>(ConfigurationModels.ContextualMenus, this.ApplicationContext.Application.ProductId);
    if (requestedInfo.Text && !replaceEntitiesConfig.DocTypes.IsEmpty())
    {
        var docType = this.GetDocument(docRequest, new DocumentRequestOptions { DocType = true }, DecoratorTypes.None).DocType;
        return replaceEntitiesConfig.DocTypes.Any(x => x.Equals(docType, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    }
    return false;
}
```

With LINQ statement, exception is thrown, and the exception is thrown even before docType is initialized. Without it (using foreach instead), it works perfectly. **Both codes should work the same way (even ReSharper suggests me to change the foreach for the LINQ expression), but with LINQ it's failing.**

For the case that it doesn't work, **it doesn't go any further than this line**
`var docType = this.GetDocument(docRequest, new DocumentRequestOptions { DocType = true }, DecoratorTypes.None).DocType;`
**though it worked before (the only change is that after this line the program logic is done with a LINQ statement instead of a foreach)**

Values:

- docType = "LE" (I see it from the way exception is not thrown, or in the case it's thrown, debugging the GetDocument method).
- replaceEntitiesConfig.DocTypes = `new List<string>();`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77521/discussion-on-question-by-juan-i-cornet-recchimuzzi-linq-is-provoking-a-system).

Answer (score 1):

You're probably building Release configuration, where some optimizations are in effect. In your case what happens is that compiler deduces that `string docType` is not used, so it removes it from code, and then compiler figures out that `DocumentResponseModel responseForDocType` is not used as well, which is also removed from code. Non-existent code does not cause exceptions.

But once one of the lines that actually uses `responseForDocType` is introduced, we also must have the line that creates the thing, and then we have the exception.

TL;DR - build in Debug configuration, and see the difference.

Comment: The compiler is not allowed to perform optimizations that change observable program behavior.

Comment: Building in Debug. Happens in Debug :/. I already though of that

Comment: @Juan maybe the option "Optimize code" is turned on in debug build. Maybe you build debug, but still run release.

Comment: @Dialecticus Just checked. Debug has "Optimize code" unchecked. "Release" has it checked

Comment: @Juan what happens if you put a break point on `this.GetDocument` line? What do you see if you "Go To Dissassembly" on that line? As an alternative, place a break point _inside_ `GetDocument`. Also, what is the difference in Dissassembly window when LINQ line is commented and uncommented?

Comment: Also, user usr has a point, there is not enough information in the question, so the question is at fault. I sense we're going to "overchat" the issue, so I better stop it now, before it takes more time from me.

Comment: @Dialecticus GetDocument is working and returning a initialized object with the property DocType set to "LE".
replaceEntitiesConfig.DocTypes value is new List<string>(). Check the new code I uploaded. With the foreach, code works fine, with LINQ, it fails and throws the exception